# Trying to join two tables and display the proper information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
@followers = current_user.followers.joins(:received_messages).uniq.order("id DESC")
```

Quick explanation, it grabs the current users followers and joins them with the message, sent/received. And shows only one at a time.

I'm using this to show the 'messages' in an inbox that part works fine, by i want to order that inbox by the latest sent OR received messages id.

Right now my view looks like this, (which is a hell of a mess, i know there's some way for me to do it cleaner in ruby)

```
-if f.sent_messages.first && f.received_messages.first
  -if f.sent_messages.last.id > f.received_messages.last.id
    p This is running
    =image_tag f.avatar
    h2= f.uid
    p= f.sent_messages.last.body
    =link_to "Go To Conversation", conversation_path(:id => f.sent_messages.last.sender_id)
  -else
    =image_tag f.avatar
    h2= f.uid
    p= f.received_messages.last.body
    =link_to "Go To Conversation", conversation_path(:id => f.received_messages.last.receiver_id)
  end
-elsif f.sent_messages.first && f.received_messages.first == nil
  =image_tag f.avatar
  h2= f.uid
  p= f.sent_messages.last.body
  =link_to "Go To Conversation", conversation_path(:id => f.sent_messages.last.sender_id)
-elsif f.sent_messages.first == nil && f.received_messages.first
  =image_tag f.avatar
  h2= f.uid
  p= f.received_messages.last.body
  =link_to "Go To Conversation", conversation_path(:id => f.received_messages.last.receiver_id)
```

Comment: The reason I have this massive elsif statement is because if one of the users didn't have sent or received messages in this category it would break the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-if f.sent_messages.any? || f.received_messages.any?
  =image_tag f.avatar
  %h2 = f.uid
  -unless f.sent_messages.empty? || f.received_messages.empty?
    -message,id = f.sent_messages.last.id > f.received_messages.last.id ? [f.sent_messages.last,f.sent_messages.last.sender_id] : [f.received_messages.last, f.received_messages.last.receiver_id]
  -else
    -message,id = f.sent_messages.last.nil? ? [f.received_messages.last,f.received_messages.last.receiver_id] : [f.sent_messages.last,f.sent_messages.last.sender_id]
  %p = message.body
  =link_to "Go To Conversation", conversation_path(:id => id)
```

Comment: This broke it for some reason.  It's still detecting non-existant information for the message and throwing an error.

Comment: Can you post the error this will be useful in determining the issue

Comment: Also edited my post because I am assuming you are using haml and i forgot a few characters for running ruby code.

Comment: Yeah, give me a bit to alter this around some, i'm actually using slim.